# MySQL: Calculate sum total of all the figures in a column where has specific date

Tags: php, mysql, sum

How can I get the sum of the column price for a specific month.

The date column is a varchar(10) and the date format is European ( dd-mm-yy ).

Here is a sample of my table:

[image]

Currently to select all sum of price I use:

```
case 'get':

            $q=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);
            $query="SELECT sum(price) FROM Fuel";

            $result = mysql_query($query);


            $json = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $json['price']=$row['price'];
            }
            print json_encode($json);




            mysql_close();


            break;
```

So how can I get the sum of column price for month 09-2012.

Comment: So what is the question here?

Comment: So how can I get the sum of column price for month 09-2012.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First change the data type of your `date` column (remember to update your application code appropriately):

```sql
ALTER TABLE Fuel ADD newdate DATE;
UPDATE Fuel SET newdate = STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%m-%Y');
ALTER TABLE Fuel DROP date, CHANGE newdate date DATE FIRST;
```

Then you can:

```sql
SELECT SUM(price) FROM Fuel WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-09-01' AND '2012-09-30'
```

Comment: @jQuerybeast: It will replace your original string column with one of MySQL's internal [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) type, so MySQL will recognise and handle the data as dates, enabling you to perform operations such as the above.  The values will be transitioned (by the `UPDATE` operation).

Comment: On a side-question, can I change the format of the date? Currently is yy-mm-dd

Comment: @jQuerybeast: Internally, MySQL [stores](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html) `DATE` types as a 3-byte integer packed as `YYYY×16×32 + MM×32 + DD`; it [retrieves and displays](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) them in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format.  If you wish to retrieve values in some other format, use MySQL's [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

Answer (score 5):

This will work for you:

```
SELECT 
  sum(price) 
FROM Fuel
WHERE datefield = 'somedate';
```

But you have to watch out the format entered in the date parameter, because it will be compared as a string literal not as a date object. However, you should store these dates in a column of data type `DATE` instead.

**Update:**

> How can I select sum for all months with 09?

To select only records for a specific month, you can use the MySQL function [**`MONTH`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) like so:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(price) 
FROM Fuel
WHERE MONTH(`date`) = 9;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d503e/2)

Comment: It is not a datefield. Only its name is 'Date'. Its a varchar(10), will it still work?

Comment: If I change its data type, will I lose all the values?

Comment: @jQuerybeast - Try to create a new table with a date object. Then use an `INSERT INTO newtable SELECT from oldtable` with  `str_to_date` function to give you date objects from these string values.

Comment: How can I select sum for all months with 09? Because my dates are like 12-09-2012 for example. With your sample I can only select sum for a specific date with format dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: WHERE datefield LIKE '%-09-%';

will give you the month 09 when your text date is of the format. dd-mm-yyyy